# CFileDialog issue, When compiled for 64 bit (x64)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, openfiledialog

I have a MFC application for 32-bit environment, where I am using CFileDailog for file selection, it was fine in 32-bit application,
Now I upgraded the same application for 64-bit environment.  but here I am facing issue, when I try to select file(s), from the dialog, it is showing an error, saying, "You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission."
Below is the code I am using for the same,

```
 SelectFileOpenDialog(csFilesList, _T("Select File"), NULL, _T("Acrobat (*.pdf) | *.pdf||"),OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_HIDEREADONLY  | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST  | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT,PrevAddFolder);
 CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, NULL, NULL, dwFlags, csFilter, CWnd::FromHandle(hwndParent));
 DWORD MAXFILE = (22528 * 2);
 TCHAR* pc = new TCHAR[MAXFILE];
 memset(pc, 0, MAXFILE * sizeof(_TCHAR));
 fileDlg.m_ofn.nMaxFile = MAXFILE;
 fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrFile = pc;
 fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = lpcsCaption;
//fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrFile[0] = NULL;
 fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = lpcsInitialFolder;
```

what causing the issue in 64-bit environment?  Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Maybe `lpcsInitialFolder` is inaccessible? Since we cannot see a [mcve], there's not much we can do to help. The issue is very likely unrelated to the bitness of the target platform.

Comment: "Maybe lpcsInitialFolder is inaccessible?"      Same message I am getting for all files in any folder, and all those files are accessible.    And this error I am getting only after upgraded to x64 bit and was fine in 32-bit implementation.

Comment: I am running this on VS 2019 pro, with the following project settings, Windows SDK Version 10.0.18362.0    platform ToolSet VS 2019(V142)

Comment: I use `CFileDialog` with x64 bit builds with no issue. It has to be another system related issue. Get your application tested on another x64 computer.

Comment: I think you can improve your question by adding where the values of your variables come from. 
Otherwise people will have difficulty helping you.